# Subdomain for Laravel no effect

Tags: laravel, docker

I am trying to set up all web routes to a subdomain `dashboard`.

I edited RouteServiceProvider boot method:

```
Route::domain('dashboard.domain.dev')
                ->middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

My host file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section

127.0.0.1       domain.dev
127.0.0.1       dashboard.domain.dev
```

`APP_URL=http://domain.dev`

I can ping domain.dev and dashboard.domain.dev, showing me ip 127.0.0.1.

I restarted, flushed dns but no success... I don't know what to do to get it running.

Comment: basicly, avoid `.dev` domains if you are using a browser based on chromium. use `.test` instead

Comment: Wow, thanks for that.. it's working. Was not aware of this, just wasted hours.